# Unable to view any .db file

Tags: android, database, sqlite

There is no *.db* file in file explorer in android studio for my app. I want to see the database of this app. I want to see the database of android app,that app is using `SQLite` concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's completely normal. You can only view the sqlite database of your application if your device is rooted, or if you're using the emulator.

Without root, you can only access sqlite programmatically through your own app, even if you're just trying to see if things are working.

This is by design, sqlite on Android is a file-based database that piggy backs off the file security system of linux. In android specifically, each application is given its own home directory which only it can access, and no other application can.